# Reusing Radzen DataGrid within the same layout under an if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, radzen

I am trying to display a Radzen table on a page.

There are three scenarios which output the same table with different data.

Normally, I have to code the table three times, and assign different data to the corresponding table.

But I want to avoid repeating the codes as it may make the project harder to manage.

To use Radzen, I have to populate "@ref", assign "Data" and specify "TItem".

Can I somehow use a string or anything to represent TItem and reuse one Radzen table under an if statement?

```
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="obj" Data="IList" TItem=Class>
  ...
<RadzenDataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I guess I can clone any TItem into 1 new temporary TItem when needed. This achieves the 're-using' purpose of the DataGrid as now only one DataGrid is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reuse a Radzen DataGrid with different TItem(s).
Therefore, you should clone items into a common class and display them in the 'reused' DataGrid.
Then, you can edit, add, and delete the data with the corresponding TItem.